# How can I get the penultimate element in an array in Swift?

Tags: swift, element

I only want the second to last element, not the last two as in:

```
let streets = ["Adams", "Bryant", "Channing", "Douglas", "Evarts"]
let penultimate = streets.suffix(2)
print(penultimate) // ["Douglas", "Evarts"]
```

Also, I do not want to use the syntax `streets[3]`, because the array is continuously filling up with entries.

Comment: `let penultimate = streets.dropLast().last`

Comment: I wonder who voted to close this question as unclear. Btw no need to vote it down before asking for clarifications. OP is a new contributo Be nice, and check out Code of Conduct. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @LeoDabus question is unclear because the OP seems to know about `suffix`, and in this case he should also know about `first`.  BTW, I wasn't the one who casted the close vote, though I agree with however did it.

Comment: @Cristik  suffix first won’t work

Comment: Thanks for the comments people. Many thanks for the assistance. Yes, I am a new contributor. I will try to make questions more clear in the future. In this case, what could I have done better?

Comment: You should always show what you have tried in this case something like `streets[streets.count-2]` and the issues you are facing (my previous example would not work for arrays with less than 2 elements) btw https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrote an extension

```
extension Array {
  func penultimate() -> Element? {
      if self.count < 2 {
          return nil
      }
      let index = self.count - 2
      return self[index]
  }
}
```

You can use it like

`yourArr.penultimate()`

Here's a Playground example, it works as intended

[image: playground]

Answer (score 6):

You can simply drop the last element of your collection and return the last element of the result:

```
extension BidirectionalCollection {
    var elementBeforeLast: Element? {
        return dropLast().last
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
if let elementBeforeLast = streets.elementBeforeLast {
    print(elementBeforeLast)  // "Douglas"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for a `Collection`.

```swift
public extension Collection {
    @inlinable
    var penultimate: Element? {
        guard let index = index(endIndex, offsetBy: -2, limitedBy: startIndex) else {
            return nil
        }
        return self[index]
    }
}
```